# How to make pygame on Apple ipad ( ios 15 )

Tags: python, pygame, pythonista

I am a coder in python. I was using pythonista and I saw a lot of people using the Scene module, but can I use pygame module?

I used Stash to install, but it doesn’t work of running the last step: setup, init.

I tried this code in stash:

```
$pip install pygame
$pip install pygame_ios
$pip install pygame @diff !version
$pip install pygame_ios @diff !version
```

But it always gives:

```
extracting zip…
running setup.py
error while running setup.py
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Please chose a title which better shows your problem, otherwise this post is at risk of receiving downvotes.

Comment: Copy everything from the moment you put the command `pip install`